# Oracle Forms Shortest Way of Display Custom Text on Item depends on Database Value of It

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

My data block item's values 1 or 0 on database. I want to display "yes" or "no" on my text item depends on its value. (If it is 1 show "yes", else (0) show "No" ) What is the shortest way of this in Oracle Forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easier to make a checkbox or listbox with the values 0 = No and 1 = Yes
Then if you switch the value your correct value is automatically saved.

Answer (score 3):

Into a `POST-QUERY` (data block level) trigger put

```
:block.text_item := case when :block.table_item = 1 then 'yes'
                         when :block.table_item = 0 then 'no'
                    end;
```

If your Forms version doesn't support `CASE` (which might be for Forms 6i and lower), use `DECODE`:

```
select decode(:block.table_item, 1, 'yes', 0, 'no')
  into :block.text_item
  from dual;
```

Comment: Thank u for quick reply. It works also but I get an error about database item usage. (10g supports CASE)

Comment: You're welcome. That's why I said that you might need to use DECODE instead.